# Why is the sizeof function returning to different values for the same array?

Tags: c, arrays, sizeof

Consider this piece of code (or just copy/paste and run it):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int array[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};

int my_put(int *array)  
{
printf("Size of array %lu\n", sizeof(array));
return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
printf("Size of array %lu\n", sizeof(array));
my_put(array);
return 0;
}
```

My question is: How come that the sizeof function returns two different values? Why is the size 28 in the `main` function and 8 in the `my_put` function?

Comment: sizeof is not a function in a first place. It's an operator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because in `my_put()`, `array` is an `int *` pointer, not an array.  Your parameter shadows the global `array` variable.  It might be clearer if you rewrite `my_put` to look like this:

```
int my_put(int *a)
{
    printf("Size of array %zu\n", sizeof array);
    printf("Size of a %zu\n", sizeof a);
    return 0;
}
```

This new function doesn't confuse two variables named `array`.  I also fixed it to use the `z` format specifier for `size_t` types.

Plenty more at the [comp.lang.c FAQ, section 6, **Arrays and Pointers**](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html), particularly [Question 6.21](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryparmsize.html) for your case.

Comment: hmm, if i use your version of `my_put` i still have the problem

Comment: It's not a *problem* - it's expected behaviour.  I added another print statement to make that clear.

Comment: so does that mean that it is not possible to pass an array as a parameter?

Comment: Well, you can pass a pointer to the array.  Isn't that good enough?

Comment: ok, last question: if i pass a pointer, how can I create an array from that pointer?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow - isn't the pointer itself enough?

Comment: well, I need the size of an array. how can I get that from a pointer that points to an array?

Comment: You cannot.  You must pass the size as a separate parameter.

Answer (score 0):

In my_put name **array** is shadowed by your func's arg and its size is 8 (since it is a pointer). In main you get size of your 'real' array. That's all

Answer (score 0):

In function `my_put` , `array` is pointer and its size is of the size of `int *`. Read [C-FAQ 6.21](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryparmsize.html).

Answer (score 0):

Because its not the same "array".  You have two arrays here -- the global variable "array" and the argument "array" to `my_put`.  Now the second one is actually a pointer that points at the first one, but its a distinct variable with a different type (int pointer vs int array), so it has a different size.